# What is the best way to add a secondary action to a row in a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, android, ios, lists, actions

I'm working on an app that allows the user to browse through a list of items. All of these items have a primary action (compose) and some of them also have a secondary action (search). As of now I'm using this structure:

[image: Structure Example]

However, I feel like it's not entirely clear what the primary action is or that there is one. This could be solved by adding an explicit button for the primary action, but this would result in a repetitive pattern of buttons. Plus it's usual for mobile applications to bind the primary action to the entire row.

Do any of you have a clever solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I think Composing a new item and doing a search are two very different things and that the person working with your application wouldn't expect to have two actions on the same control (which by the way goes against any convention).

Could you provide more details? What is the main goal of the person seeing this view? Compose or Search? I think you could think of Search as a general feature and not only related to each action. For instance, you could have a general search that presents the results organised by category, if that's the need.

Answer (score 0):

**People tend to use middle of the mobile screen more frequently and more feasibly so put your functionality there**

So if each row have actions related to them, then why don't you put both actions in each row (content area) and if some row don't have search, just skip it....

Also it doesn't make sense by putting compose at top and search in each row as both are related to each item (Am i right?)

Sometimes repetition is good e.g Each email item having Reply, Forward buttons with them so don't worry about repeating things

Answer (score 0):

I would not prefer repeating the action buttons for all the items on your list.Have a single action button for compose.May be in the top bar or a floating action bar(If its android), something similar to the Gmail app, when you want to compose a mail.[example for compose](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/fabulous.png) When it comes to search it should be a single icon on the top.For consistency user should be allowed to search across all your items.I am not very sure of your context here.